# How to use current user home directory in key.propreties

Tags: android, flutter

I am deploying my flutter app.
https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#create-a-keystore

It worked fine. But I am developing using several windows machine with different username.

So everytime I build, I have to change the username in key.properties for the storeFile value.

I trie using the %username% environment variable of windows:

```
keyAlias=key
storeFile=c:/Users/%USERNAME%/key.jks
```

But i does not work

```
Keystore file 'c:\Users\%USERNAME%\key.jks' not found for signing config 'release'.
```